# How to construct these HQL statements

Tags: hibernate

Do anyone know how to construct these two SQL statement in HQL;

```
     SELECT MIN(id) FROM Books WHERE mid < ?  OR mid =?

     SELECT SUM(noOfBooks) FROM Bookcount WHERE mId=128
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should work in HQL just fine. If you provide more details about the troubles you experience maybe we can help further.

```
Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT SUM(noOfBooks) FROM Bookcount WHERE mId=128");
Long result = (Long) q.uniqueResult();
```

And btw `mid < ?  OR mid =?` can be rewritten just like `mid <= ?`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the sql columns with their HQL object mappings as specified in your hibernate mapping file. For example,

```
select min(b.id) from Book b where b.mId = 123
```

and

```
select sum(bc.numberOfBooks) from BookCount bc where bc.mId = 123
```